# backbone.js: how can I partially update the model json object using .set()?

Tags: backbone.js

My backbone.js model has a json object in defaults like this:

```
test: { 
    testArr: [{
        obj1: value1,
        obj2: value2
    }]
}
```

How can I update just a part of the model for eg: test.testArr[0].obj1 using this.model.set()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to extract the array from the properties, update it, and inject it back in. Assuming your model is called `model`, that would look like:

```
var newTestArr = model.get('testArr');
newTestArr.obj1 = 'foobar';
model.set({testArr: newTestArr});
```

Comment: Just realized that `test` is the actual object in question...at the top level, just extract `test`, edit `test.testArr.obj1`, and put it back

Comment: Thanks, that worked! The change event doesn't get triggered for the model when I do this but I think maybe that's not related to how I modify the model.